# Positioning a movieclip onto another movieclip 2

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating a game where if you hit a zombie the zombie dies and his head is sent back in the direction you hit. It is like playing baseball with the zombies head with the head being the ball. I have two movieclips the zombie and the zombie head. Once the zombie is hit it will play its dying animation and remove itself and at the same time the zombie head will be added to the x and y co-ordinates of the dying zombie and be blown back like playing baseball. I have done the code for the hittest and the zombie dying and respawning but I can't seem to position and add the head to the dying zombie when it is hit. I have done the function for the zombie head but how can I add it to the zombie. I thought it will be like this, I added this in the PlayDeathAnimation function in the zombie class but did not work:

```
for (var i=0; i < MovieClip(parent).zombies.length; ++i)
{
var zh = new ZombieHead();
zh.x = MovieClip(parent).zombies[i].x;
zh.y = MovieClip(parent).zombies[i].y;  
zh.rotation = MovieClip(parent).zombies[i].rotation;                
addChild(zh);

}
```

I even tried just this. The head does spawn but just stays static and does not fly back and it removes itself when the zombie removes itself which I don't wan't. I have already told the ZombieHead when to remove itself in its own class

```
var zh = new ZombieHead();               
addChild(zh);
```

This is what i done so far 
Player

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.utils.setTimeout;

    public class Player extends MovieClip
    {
        //Player Setting
        var walkSpeed:Number = 4;
        var walkRight:Boolean = false;
        var walkLeft:Boolean = false;
        var walkUp:Boolean = false;
        var walkDown:Boolean = false;
        var attacking:Boolean = false;
        var attackRange:int = 100;
        var attackAngle:int = 30;

        public function Player()
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,walk);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Update);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,stopWalk);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,attack);
            // The lines below draw a preview of your attack area
            graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00, 0.2);
            graphics.lineTo(attackRange*Math.cos((rotation-attackAngle)/180*Math.PI),attackRange*Math.sin((rotation-attackAngle)/180*Math.PI));
            graphics.lineTo(attackRange*Math.cos((rotation+attackAngle)/180*Math.PI),attackRange*Math.sin((rotation+attackAngle)/180*Math.PI));
            graphics.endFill();


        }

        function walk(event:KeyboardEvent)
        {
            //When Key is Down
            if (event.keyCode == 68)
            {
                walkRight = true;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 87)
            {
                walkUp = true;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 65)
            {
                walkLeft = true;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 83)
            {
                walkDown = true;
            }
        }

        function Update(event:Event)
        {

            //if attacking is true then key moves are false;
            if ((attacking == true))
            {
                walkRight = false;
                walkLeft = false;
                walkUp = false;
                walkDown = false;
                // see if the zombie is in the cone

                for (var i:int=MovieClip(parent).zombies.length-1; i>=0; i--)
                {
                    if (inAttackCone(MovieClip(parent).zombies[i]))
                    {
                        if (hitTestObject(MovieClip(parent).zombies[i]))
                        {
                            //attacking = true;
                            MovieClip(parent).zombies[i].zombieDead = true;
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
            else if ((attacking == false))
            {
                //Else if attacking is false then move and rotate to mouse;
                var dx = parent.mouseX - x;
                var dy = parent.mouseY - y;
                var angle = Math.atan2(dy,dx) / Math.PI * 180;
                rotation = angle;

                if ((walkRight == true))
                {
                    x +=  walkSpeed;
                    gotoAndStop(2);
                }
                if ((walkUp == true))
                {
                    y -=  walkSpeed;
                    gotoAndStop(2);
                }
                if ((walkLeft == true))
                {
                    x -=  walkSpeed;
                    gotoAndStop(2);
                }
                if ((walkDown == true))
                {
                    y +=  walkSpeed;
                    gotoAndStop(2);
                }
            }
        }

        //Calculate the distance between the two
        public function distanceBetween(player:MovieClip,zombies:MovieClip):Number
        {
            for (var i:int=MovieClip(parent).zombies.length-1; i>=0; i--)
            {
                var dx:Number = x - MovieClip(parent).zombies[i].x;
                var dy:Number = y - MovieClip(parent).zombies[i].y;
            }
            return Math.sqrt(((dx * dx) + dy * dy));
        }

        public function angleDifference(a:Object, b:Object):Number
        {
            var dx:Number = b.x - a.x;
            var dy:Number = b.y - a.y;
            var ang:Number = (a.rotation/180*Math.PI)-Math.atan2(dy, dx);
            while (ang>Math.PI)
            {
                ang -=  2 * Math.PI;
            }
            while (ang<-Math.PI)
            {
                ang +=  2 * Math.PI;
            }
            return Math.abs(ang*180/Math.PI);
        }

        function inAttackCone(enemy:MovieClip):Boolean
        {
            var distance:Number = distanceBetween(this,enemy);
            distance -=  enemy.width / 2;// account for the enemy's size
            if (distance < attackRange)
            {
                // In range, check angle
                if (angleDifference(this,enemy)<attackAngle)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        function stopWalk(event:KeyboardEvent)
        {
            if ((attacking == false))
            {
                if (event.keyCode == 68)
                {
                    event.keyCode = 0;
                    walkRight = false;
                    gotoAndStop(1);
                }
                if (event.keyCode == 87)
                {
                    event.keyCode = 0;
                    walkUp = false;
                    gotoAndStop(1);
                }
                if (event.keyCode == 65)
                {
                    event.keyCode = 0;
                    walkLeft = false;
                    gotoAndStop(1);
                }
                if (event.keyCode == 83)
                {
                    event.keyCode = 0;
                    walkDown = false;
                    gotoAndStop(1);
                }
            }
        }

        function attack(event:MouseEvent)
        {
            if ((attacking == false))
            {
                attacking = true;
                gotoAndStop(3);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Zombie

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class Zombie extends MovieClip
    {

        var walkSpeed:Number = 2;
        var target:Point;
        public var zombieDead:Boolean = false;

        public function Zombie()
        {
            //set target location of Zombie
            target = new Point(Math.random() * 500,Math.random() * 500);
        }

        function loop()
        {
            if (zombieDead == true)
            {
                playDeathAnimation();
            }
            else if (zombieDead == false)
            {
                gotoAndStop(1);
                //Point Zombie at its target
                var dx = MovieClip(root).Player01.x - x;
                var dy = MovieClip(root).Player01.y - y;
                var angle = Math.atan2(dy,dx) / Math.PI * 180;
                rotation = angle;
                //Move in the direction the zombie is facing
                x = x+Math.cos(rotation/180*Math.PI)*walkSpeed;
                y = y+Math.sin(rotation/180*Math.PI)*walkSpeed;
                //Calculate the distance to target
                var hyp = Math.sqrt((dx*dx)+(dy*dy));
                if (hyp<5)
                {
                    target.x = Math.random() * 500;
                    target.y = Math.random() * 500;
                }
            }
        }

        public function playDeathAnimation()
        {
            gotoAndStop(2);
        }

        public function deathAnimationFinishedCallback()
        {
            for (var i=0; i < MovieClip(parent).zombies.length; ++i)
            {
                if (MovieClip(parent).zombies[i] == this)
                {
                    MovieClip(parent).zombies.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            MovieClip(parent).removeChild(this);
        }
    }

}
```

ZombieHead

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;


    public class ZombieHead extends MovieClip
    {

        var headSpeed:Number = -30;
        var friction:Number = 0.9;


        public function ZombieHead()
        {
            // constructor code
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Update);

        }

        function Update(event:Event)
        {
                x = x+Math.cos(rotation/180*Math.PI)*headSpeed;
                y = y+Math.sin(rotation/180*Math.PI)*headSpeed;
                headSpeed *=  friction;
                if (headSpeed > -0.00001)
                {
                    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Update);
                    parent.removeChild(this);
                }
                else if (x<0 || x > 550 || y < 0 || y > 400)
                {
                    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Update);
                    parent.removeChild(this);
                }
        }

    }

}
```

Document Class

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Game extends MovieClip
    {
        public var zombies:Array;

        public function Game()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
            zombies = new Array();
        }

        public function update(e:Event)
        {
            //Only spawn a Zombie if there are less than number
            if (numChildren < 4)
            {
                //Make a new instance of the Zombie.
                var Z = new Zombie();
                addChild(Z);

                //Position and rotate the zombie
                Z.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                Z.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
                Z.rotation = Math.random() * 360;

                zombies.push(Z);
            }
            for (var count = 0; count<zombies.length; count ++)
            {
                zombies[count].loop();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to track the x,y values for the head to follow the body, an enterFrame function would do:
for example:

```
       addEventListner(event.ENTER_FRAME,follow head);

       function (event.ENTER_FRAME){
                 myhead.x == mybody.x
                 myhead.y == mybody.y 
                 }
```

Basically thehead will follow the body x,y values every frame or within every frame cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You apparently are adding the head to the zombie, not to the holder class, and then, when you remove the zombie, you remove the head of it too, as that head is the child of the zombie. Do add it to the parent of that zombie:

```
parent.addChild(zh);
```

Also, in order to move those heads, the parent class should be made aware of a head arriving. So, as you are adding a head, and you have an array of zombies, make an array of them heads which will be populated while heads will spawn, and depopulated when you would want your heads to disappear, and iterate through it as you apparently already do with zombies.

Comment: It nearly worked, this is what I done. In the player class

    for (var i:int=MovieClip(parent).zombies.length-1; i>=0; i--){
     if (inAttackCone(MovieClip(parent).zombies[i])){
      if (hitTestObject(MovieClip(parent).zombies[i])){
       MovieClip(parent).zombies[i].zombieDead = true;
              var zh = new ZombieHead;
       zh.x = MovieClip(parent).zombies[i].x;
       zh.y = MovieClip(parent).zombies[i].y;
       zh.rotation = MovieClip(parent).zombies[i].rotation;
       parent.addChild(zh);
       }
      }

     }
    }

Comment: But the problem is the ZombieHead will recreate itself many times until the zombie is dead. The head functions as how it is suppose to function and gets rid of itself how it should but I think as long as zombiedead = true it will constantly recreate itself until zombiedead is false. How can i come up with a solution that only one head will be added when zombiedead is true.

Comment: Never mind, i got it working, thank you sooooo much i was stuck for like a week. I just need to do parent.addChild and change some boolean around